# R + Sql Server Script output to csv using R

Tags: sql, sql-server, r, csv

I am trying to run a process that rolls over several time periods using data that sits in a Sql Server 2008 R2 Database.  If it were smaller I'd pull it all in to R and just subset based on date.  However the data is ~15GB and I need to be able to generate csv files directly from Sql Server (I've found the R-Sql connectors to be too slow to move large amounts of data) via the R-SQL connector (RODBC, etc.) and then read them into R.

It seems that sqlcmd or bcp are the only options but I wanted to check before going in that direction.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I use the package RODBC a lot it works like a charm, large query using sqlQuery can take some times though. Once the query is done you will get a dataframe that you can easily export in csv via write.csv. It will work without any issues.